# List structure transformation

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures

How to transform a list as

```
{{x,y},{a,b,c,d,e}}
```

into the form of

```
{{x,y,a},{x,y,b},{x,y,c},{x,y,d},{x,y,e}}
```

elegantly, without using a loop such as `For`?

Comment: `{p, q} = {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}};
Append[p, #] & /@ q`

Comment: `Outer[Join, {p}, Partition[q, 1], 1, 1][[1]]`

Comment: `First[Outer[Flatten@*List, {#1}, #2, 1, 2] & @@ {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}}]`

Comment: `Join[p, {#}] & /@ q`

Comment: just because I like `Reap`/`Sow`: `Last@Reap[Sow @@ {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}}, _, Append[#2[[1]], #1] &]`

Comment: @ubpdqn I was sure `Join[]` was going to be quicker, turns out I was wrong :/. Your first comment is the most efficient of all of these.

Comment: @Feyre  I guess it depends on aim and exact input...both work :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Flatten /@ Thread[data, List, {2}]
```

> {{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}

Also:

```
Append @@@ Tuples[{{#}, #2}] & @@ data
```

> {{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}

Comment: Oh! This looks nice! And thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[dat]
dat = {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
Append[dat[[1]], #] & /@ dat[[2]]
```

> {{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}

Also this may offer some added advantages

```
Table[Join[dat[[1]], {dat[[2, i]]}], {i, Length[dat[[2]]]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a good place to use `MapThread`. Problem is that it wants both lists to be the same length. So use `Table` to make it so.

```
{p, q} = {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}}; MapThread[Append, {Table[p,Length[q]], q}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple way to do it.

```
data = {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}};
{data[[1, 1]], data[[1, 2]], #}& /@ data[[2]]
```

> `{{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}`

Answer (score 2):

It's usually nice to have at least one method that preserves packed arrays, when the two lists in the input are packed arrays.

```
PadLeft[ArrayReshape[#2, {Length@#2, 1}], {Length@#2, 1 + Length@#1}, 
   Reverse@#1] & @@ {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
(*  {{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}  *)

a1 = RandomInteger[9, 200];
a2 = RandomInteger[{100, 110}, 50000];

PadLeft[ArrayReshape[#2, {Length@#2, 1}], {Length@#2, 1 + Length@#1}, 
    Reverse@#1] & @@ {a1, a2} // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*  True  *)
```

---

For fun, a couple of obscure ones, which make nice puzzles:

```
Through[(Append /@ #2)[#1]] & @@ {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
(*  {{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}  *)

Flatten@Level[Map @@ {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}}, {2}, Heads -> True] ~Partition~ 3
(*  {{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{p, q} = {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}};`

```
Table[Append[p, q[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@q}]
```

or

```
Outer[Join, {p}, Partition[q, 1], 1, 1][[1]]
```

or

```
Join[p, {#}] & /@ q
```

all give

> {{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}

Answer (score 1):

```
{p, q} = {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceReplace[q, {s_} :> Append[p, s]]
```

{{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}

Using `SubsetReplace` (new in 12.1)

```
SubsetReplace[q, {s_} :> Append[p, s]]
```

{{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}

Using `ReplacePart` and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
ReplacePart[q, i_ :> {Splice @ p, q[[i]]}]
```

{{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}};
```

Using `Thread` and `ConstantArray`:

```
Append @@@ Thread[{ConstantArray[#1, Length@#2], #2} & @@ data]

(*{{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {{x, y}, {a, b, c, d, e}}
Thread[Append[Sequence @@ list]]

Distribute[list, Apply[Thread@*Append]]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{x, y, a}, {x, y, b}, {x, y, c}, {x, y, d}, {x, y, e}}